# couchbase c# client. how to query a view with compound key and date range

Tags: c#, .net, mapreduce, nosql, couchbase

i have a requirement where i need to query a view that i created. the view itself generates a compound key. 
for example say i have a view that looks like this

```
function (doc) {    
 emit([doc.name,dateToArray(doc.startDate)], null);

}
```

i want to query the view where `name="x" and ( startdate > dateA and < dateB)`.

is it even possible to do this in the c# client for couch base ?

i have tried using normal keys but i could not get the view query working with compound keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Couchbase Manual has a really good example on how to do this -

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#views-in-a-schema-less-database

Scroll to the section titled "Selecting Compound Information by key or keys"

Keys are matched from left to right. The one caveat to date/time selection is that your end range will necessarily use hours that don't exist, and your end query may result in more records than you want.  That is by design - your application layer should perform the final filtering of records before returning them.